# Кодировка csv файла и отображение в excel

Tags: c#, excel, кодировка, csv, utf-8

Создаю csv файл с кодировкой UTF8 и кириллицей. Если в начале файла не указывать разделитель `sup=,` то Excel читает кириллицу как надо, однако, при явном указании разделителя вместо кириллицы иероглифы, причем на разных версиях Excel разные. Сделать без явного указания разделителя плохо, т.к. на разных версиях Excel разделитель либо `,` либо `;`.

```
string Str = "sep=,"+ Environment.NewLine  +  "Отчет об ошибках за  " +  FileDate + Environment.NewLine
            + "Элемент модели, Тег, Сообщение об ошибке, Метка времени, Процент плохих значений за час"
            + Environment.NewLine + ModelElName + "," + TagName + ","
            + ErrorMsg_timeStamp.ElementAt(ErrorMsg_timeStamp.Count - 1).Item1 + ","
            + ErrorMsg_timeStamp.ElementAt(ErrorMsg_timeStamp.Count - 1).Item2 + ","
            + BadValuePercent + Environment.NewLine;
File.AppendAllText(Filepath, Str,Encoding.UTF8);
```

Comment: Попробуйте использовать кодировку UTF8 BOM, в ваш файл добавьте в самом начале коды символов 0xEF,0xBB,0xBF

Comment: Notepad++ говорит, что кодировка созданного файла UTF8 BOM, видит кириллицу как надо, excel, увы, нет.